# Regex: Combine negative lookahead and regular search

Tags: regex

I would like to combine two regular expressions. The first one is a negative lookahead:

```
^(.(?!(test)))*$
```

It matches my data that does not contain "test".

Now I would like to combine it with a basic search: I would like to find data that does not contain "test" (string 1) but does contain "fix" (string 2). How can I combine these two into a single regular expression?

For my purpose it doesn't matter where these strings appear, as long as "test" does not appear and "fix" does appear.

Comment: What is the language? You can use just something like `!string.Contains("test") && string.Contains("fix")`. Should the strings `test` and `fix` be matched as whole words, case insensitive? Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?!.*test)(?=.*fix)(.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xe5_hH1I-mRbjlK8)

is a general solution for this. it doesn't really matter what order the lookarounds are in since the regex cursor will not move until the lookarounds have been parsed.

the only thing I want to say about this, and I made it this way because thats what your regex is like, is that if there are words like `fixed` or `tested`, those will be caught by the look aheads. you can change this by adding word boundaries

```
^(?!.*\btest\b)(?=.*\bfix\b)(.*)$
```

EDIT: if you want to match across multiple lines, take out /m and replace with /s or change `.` token

```
^(?![\s\S]*test)(?=[\s\S]*fix)([\s\S]*)$
```

Comment: What if the string has line breaks, and `fix` is on the second line?

Comment: change the /m tag to a /s flag so that `.*` matches newlines as well. or replace anyinstance of `.` with something like `[\s\S]`

Comment: Yes, unless it is Qt where `.` matches a newline and `[\s\S]` is not necessary.

Comment: yeah, it really depends on the engine that OP is using

Answer (score 1):

Either of these ways will work:

Type 1

```
 # ^(?!.*test)(?=.*fix).*$

 ^ 
 (?! .* test )
 (?= .* fix )
 .* 
 $
```

Type 2

```
 # ^(?:(?!test).)*fix(?:(?!test).)*$

 ^ 
 (?:
      (?! test )
      . 
 )*
 fix
 (?:
      (?! test )
      . 
 )*
 $
```