# Regext that start with but does not containt

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex for a redirect rule that will include folders from 2010 to 2012 but exclude two very specific page slugs. My URLs are setup like the following:

/2016/09/18/my-page-slug/

The two pages are:

/2011/04/11/some-page/
/2012/06/15/another-page-2/

I have something like ^/2010|2011|2012/.* that matches all subdirectories that start in those years, not sure how to do an exception for those page slugs.

I probably need a negative lookahead something like (?!some-page|another-page-2) but not sure how to set it up.

Comment: you have to use a negative lookahead to match something that doesn't contain a string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639856/regex-combine-negative-lookahead-and-regular-search

Comment: @Barmar thanks this was very helpful. It definitely pointed me in the right direction. What really helped me was the debuggex link that I used to test variations on the regex until I got the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write two regexes? I mean sure if you want,

```
^\/201[012]\/\d*\/\d*\/(?!(some-page|another-page-2))
```

Do a negative look forward on either of those strings.

You have to be really specific about matching the strings and where they slug pages would be. Because you need to make sure some other thing like `.*` couldn't have already eaten what you wanted to dispose of. So you need to specify the directory so that it must be followed by the slug page, then do the negative lookahead. You'll note it stops working if you do something like `.*`(negative lookahead) because the `.*` will greedy match everything and then it's followed by `$` so all's good and the negative match doesn't discount the string.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what worked for anyone who's interested:

```
^/(?!.*slug1/|.*slug2/)(?:2010|2011|2012)(.*)$
```

What really helped me get to the right answer was this site that lets you easily test your regex: https://www.debuggex.com/